# Throwing new exception with unexpected pending exception

Tags: android, android-studio

Проект под Андроид при компиляции выкидывает вот такой екзепшн:

```
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329] Throwing new exception 'length=79; index=1337' with unexpected pending exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=79; index=1337
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void ua.avk.moicar.activity.view.LoginActivity.allCarTask2(java.lang.String) (LoginActivity.java:687)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at java.lang.Boolean ua.avk.moicar.activity.view.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(java.lang.Void[]) (LoginActivity.java:430)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at java.lang.Object ua.avk.moicar.activity.view.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(java.lang.Object[]) (LoginActivity.java:399)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at java.lang.Object android.os.AsyncTask$2.call() (AsyncTask.java:295)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:237)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run() (AsyncTask.java:234)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:818)
A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1329]
```

Почему оно так себя ведет и как исправить?
Вот код:

```
public interface UserClient {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login/")
    Call<JsonObject> getUser2(@Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                              @Field("username") String userName,
                              @Field("password") String password
    );
}
```

И есть вызов:

```
...    
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/api/")
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
                Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
                UserClient userClient = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);
   Call<JsonObject> call = userClient.getUser2("sectet", "user", "password");
    try {
        retrofit2.Response response = call.execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.i("USER -> ", "TRUE");
        } else {
            Log.i("USER -> ", "FALSE");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

...
```

В сети находил [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809271/tracking-down-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-android) - но оно не помогло

Answer (score 1):

**Нашел решение** ([оригинал решения](https://xrubio.com/2016/02/problems-with-instant-run-android-studio-2-0-beta-4-and-retrofit/))

В общем в AndroidStudio заходим в

```
File->Settings->Instant Run
```

и убираем галочку с

```
Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy (default enabled)
```

Мне помогло, надеюсь что поможет еще и Вам.

PS/ Я понимаю, что екзепшн говорит о проблеме с массивом. Но решение данной проблемы было именно таким. В сети находил еще более банальные варианты, например создать новый класс или переписать блок. (ссылок уже нет т.к. я сам такие решения не принимал всерьез).

Comment: **Для тех кто не согласен - просьба высказывать свое мнение и решение...**